# How can I call a new UIViewController within in UITabcontroller

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabContrroller(here WelcomeViewController) and when I click a button on one of it's tab item page, it shows a popover(PopViewController) with another button  for displaying a new page (SecondPageViewController),  but should show same tabs in the parent UITabContrroller.

First I tried the option Sequee from the  button of PopViewController and uncomment the prepareForSegue, but it did not work.

Later I tried to connect WelcomeViewController(where Tabbar resides)  with  seguee to SecondPage.

button code is as follows:

```
 @IBAction func goToCarerUpdateProfile(sender: UIButton) {
let careerPageView =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WelcomeViewControllerIdentifier") as! WelcomeViewController
        careerPageView.performSegueWithIdentifier("pushToCarerUpdateProfileSegue", sender: self)
}
```

This code calls  the prepareForSegue function of WelcomeViewControllerIdentifier, but there is no Second page visible.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == "pushToCarerUpdateProfileSegue" {

            print("This portion working")
            let svc = segue.destinationViewController as? CarerUpdateProfileViewController

        }
```

How can I call a new  UIViewController within in  UITabcontroller ? The conditionn is the new View should have the same tabs as previous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open a new UIViewController from an UITabcontroller ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390861/how-can-i-open-a-new-uiviewcontroller-from-an-uitabcontroller)

Comment: yes, it's my question, stakoverflow did not show a message after I post my first attempt. so posted again, I shall delete this question.